# web scraping python not fetching results

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

For a project work on text analytics, I am trying to scrape some reviews.  I am using python and beautiful soup to do the job.  I am not getting any errors but not getting any data also.  I am sure I am making mistake in specifying the div tags.  Can someone help?  The following is the code which I used:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("https://www.zomato.com/brewbot")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
links = soup.find.all("div")
k_data = soup.find_all({"class":"rev-text"})

for item in k_data:
    print item.text
```

I have changed "class":"rev-text" to "tabindex='0'", "class"-"rev.text", included the "itemprop"="description", and other combinations...nothing seem to work.  Can someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Reviews are dynamically loaded* from a response to a POST request to the `social_load_more.php` endpoint. Simulate that in your code, get the HTML with reviews from the JSON response and parse it with `BeautifulSoup`. Complete working code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


with requests.Session() as session:
    session.headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36"}
    r = session.get("https://www.zomato.com/brewbot")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
    itemid = soup.body["itemid"]

    # get reviews
    r = session.post("https://www.zomato.com/php/social_load_more.php", data={
        "entity_id": itemid,
        "profile_action": "reviews-top",
        "page": "0",
        "limit": "5"
    })
    reviews = r.json()["html"]

    soup = BeautifulSoup(reviews, "html.parser")
    k_data = soup.select("div.rev-text")

    for item in k_data:
        print(item.get_text())
```