# No Output with Beautiful Soup find_all

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

urla = 'https://www.tumblr.com/search/hello'

r = requests.get(urla)

soupa = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

links = soupa.find_all("div", {"class": "header_mage_wrapper has_avatar"})

for link in links:

    print link
```

So after I run this code, nothing breaks and I get exit code 0 (using PyCharm), however there is no output at all.

If I take away {"class": "header_mage_wrapper has_avatar"})
so there is just the find_all ("div"), it works perfectly fine and pulls out all the divs. I tried this same code with a different website and had no problems with it, I'm sure it's something small that I just don't know yet, I have only been using BeautifulSoup for a day or two, but I can't find the problem since there is no coding error being done.

Thank you!

Comment: in the source for the page you gave the link to i cannot find `header_mage_wrapper has_avatar` . Can you check that?

Comment: How did you determine that there is a div with those classes? Not that there is any such class, but `header_mage_wrapper` looks like a misspelling of `header_image_wrapper`.

Comment: It's likely you're trying to parse javascript, which needs to be done a bit different, and as Martijn mentioned - you've probably not spelled the class correctly anyway.

Comment: I definitely am spelling it right, but I think that I'L'l has a point with it being javascript because when I inspect the element on the webpage it pops up just fine, but when using requests to pull the html it doesn't pop up there, so I'll check out how to work with javascript. Thank you all for the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This fetches you no output :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
urla = 'https://www.tumblr.com/search/hello'
r = requests.get(urla)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)

for link in soup.find_all('div', class_="header_image_wrapper has_avatar"):
    print(link.get('class'))
```

This is because the `get()` is not fetching `header_image_wrapper` class.
The lowest decedent it fetches is `search_blog_row`.

The `header_image_wrapper` you are searching for is loaded dynamically based on your search.

So you may try a `POST` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35894388/web-scraping-python-not-fetching-results).

**Instead I would suggest use the [Tumblr API](https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2) to get the results.**

Comment: I think you're right with the API. I'll learn how to use that instead.

Comment: @Sweetcheeks12354 Good.